# Entity framework slows down while creating objects in a loop

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have an employee class as follows

```cs
[Table("employee")]
[DataContract(Name = "employee"]
public class Employee
    {

        [Key]
        [DataMember(Name = "Id", IsRequired = true)]
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "Name", IsRequired = true)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [DataMember(Name = "empCode", IsRequired = true)]
        public int Code{ get; set; }
}
```

In Another class I am creating records for the above table using a foreach loop. newEmps is a result set of a different query which returs specific data.

```cs
var empList= new List<Employee>();
foreach (var employee in newEmps)
{
    var emp= new Employee();
    emp.ID = employee.ID;
    emp.Name = employee.Name;
    emp.Code = employee.code;
    empList.Add(emp);
}
```

count of newEmps is around 6500, while creating 6500 Employee object, Entity slows down and this foreach loop execution takes more than 10 mins which is more than the timeout  which is 300 seconds.

In some scenarios this works, but in some it throws following exception.  - System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out.

This exception occurs for most of the time, but sometime this works as well.

Comment: try batching in lots of say 100...ie commit a save upon every 100th in loop

Comment: I'm using SqlBulkCopy to perform Bulk inserts.

Comment: When really the shown code have this issue then the problem is not creating but the query in newEmps

Comment: Query of newEmps returns proper data, it slows down while creating 6500 Employee Objects. The for each loop takes very long time.

Comment: is it the new employee creation? or the saving part? because you wont hit `sqlexception` with just creating new `foreach` loop. so i think the exception is in saving

Comment: Object creation should not take much time. I have simulated around 10000 employees and i got the result in 0.5 seconds. I suggest tracking the problem by using `Stopwatch` or post the complete logic

Answer (score 0):

Try to use BulkInsert to resolve `System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException`

```cs
var empList= new List<Employee>();
foreach (var employee in newEmps)
{
    var emp= new Employee();
    emp.ID = employee.ID;
    emp.Name = employee.Name;
    emp.Code = employee.code;
    empList.Add(emp);
}
yourContext.BulkInsert(empList);  //★BulkInsert
```

---

**UPDATE #1**

About slow foreach loop.

If you roughly know the range, try to use [List(Int32)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.-ctor?view=netframework-4.8#System_Collections_Generic_List_1__ctor_System_Int32_)

For example:

```cs
var empList= new List<Employee>(10000);
```

Comment: Issue is with foreach loop, creation of 6500 Employee takes a lot of time.

Comment: So, then you have two problems:

1. Slow foreach loop (as you say). Reason is still unknown.
2. System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired. A possible solution I described in answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem in tracking of newEmps entities. In EF queried entities automatically tracked by the context to allow you to modify them (if necessary) and then save the changes with context.SaveChanges() operations.

Disabling tracking may speed up your application. If you use newEmps only for reading you can try query newEmps with AsNoTracking() like this.

```
var newEmps = await context.DbSet.AsNoTracking().FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Or you can change tracking behavior in foreach loop just by changing context tracking behavior.

```
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking;
var empList= new List<Employee>();
foreach (var employee in newEmps)
{
    var emp= new Employee();
    emp.ID = employee.ID;
    emp.Name = employee.Name;
    emp.Code = employee.code;
    empList.Add(emp);
}
context.ChangeTracker.QueryTrackingBehavior = QueryTrackingBehavior.TrackAll;
```

Here two usefull articles about EF tracking performance.

[Use AsNoTracking to speed up Entity Framework performance](http://www.krisvandermast.com/post/2018/02/03/Use-AsNoTracking-to-speed-up-Entity-Framework-performance.html)

[Part 3. Use AsNoTracking(). But wisely](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/3-ways-to-improve-the-ef-core-performance-in-your-net-core-app-d9b6295188cc)

Comment: I am using a linq to sql query which is IQueryable<T>, so in the foreach loop the actual query gets executing. I tried calling .toList on newEmps, it stuck there also.